# Why the result of np.mean(x.flatten()==y) is different from np.mean(x==y)?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

When I do a machining learning experiment and compute the accuracy, I found something strange.

The result of `np.mean(scores.flatten()==y)` is different from `np.mean(scores==y)`?

Because of shape difference?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

y:[-1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1  1
1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1
-1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1
-1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 ]
scores:[-1. -1. -1. -1.  1.  1.  1. -1.  1. -1. -1. -1.  1. -1.  1.  1.  1. -1. 1.  1.  1. -1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.  1.  1. -1.  1. -1.  1.  1. -1. -1.-1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1. -1. -1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.  1. -1.  1.  1. -1 -1. -1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1. ]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider posting code and any results/errors as text and not as images.

Comment: please paste values of `X` and `Y`

Comment: Is it like I just modified？May be the values of x and y are not so important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I believe problem is due to shape, to be more precise how broadcasting works.
Basically, you compare first value from `scores` with whole array for `y`, second value from `scores` with whole array for `y`, and so on and so forth.

Simple illustration - 200 random integers [1...10], in two arrays with different shapes, so should expect some of them to be equal, but mean values would be different because of broadcasting rules

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(312345)

q = np.reshape(rng.integers(0, 10, size=200), (-1, 1)) # array with (200,1) shape
t = rng.integers(0, 10, size=200) # array with (200,) shape

z = q.flatten() # values from q array with (200,) shape

print(np.mean(z == t))
print(np.mean(q == t))
print("---------------------------------")
print(q.shape)
print(z.shape)
print(t.shape)
print("---------------------------------")
print(len(z == t))
print(len((q == t).flatten()))
```

And it will print

```
0.1
0.0998
---------------------------------
(200, 1)
(200,)
(200,)
---------------------------------
200
40000
```

See last line? You have 200*200 items due to broadcasting